# UDP socket not reading packets

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp

So I have a device connected to my network card and it sends data to port 11678 and address 192.168.121.1 using IPv4 and UDP. I have checked that the device does actually send to that port and address using IPv4 and UDP by calling tcpdump. However my C socket does not receive any packets. Below I have a minimum non-working example that just runs an infinite loop until one packet is received. It does not receive any packets even though tcpdump does, so I assume something is wrong with my code.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DEST_ADDR "192.168.121.1"
#define DEST_PORT 11678
#define PACKET_MAXSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
    bzero(&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));
    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    /* create socket */
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0); // use SOCK_NONBLOCK?
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Could not create socket.");
    }

    /* bind port and address to socket */
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(DEST_PORT);
    inet_aton(DEST_ADDR, &dest_addr.sin_addr);
    int rc = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));
    if (rc != 0) {
        perror("Could not bind socket to local address");
    }

    /* read packets */
    void* buf;
    posix_memalign(&buf, 4096, 1024);
    while (true) {
        ssize_t read_size = read(fd, buf, PACKET_MAXSIZE);
        printf("%d\n", read_size);
        if (read_size > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `read` just returns -1 and sets errno to 11 (`EAGAIN`) in every iteration. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First things first: Try and check your IP and whether it falls in the valid range of IPs. Then, if possible, make the device to  send UDP packets on a broadcast IP 192.168.121.255, port unchanged. If that works, then something is wrong with IPs and not your code.

Comment: Try binding to INADDR_ANY instead of a specific IP address. `EAGAIN` just means there was no data. If you don't have anything else to do when this happens, why are you using `SOCK_NONBLOCK`?

Comment: I believe I've already tried `INADDR_ANY`, but I'll try it again for debugging. However in the final version of the software the read packets should only be for the specified address. I will also try the broadcast suggestion, but unfortunately won't be able to use the device until next week. The reason for `SOCK_NONBLOCK` is that the example above is based on a more complex program where a user might specify a flag to stop the reading loop which will be running in a background thread. As @secretsquirrel has suggested below, I could leave out `SOCK_NONBLOCK` and use `epoll`/`select` instead.

Comment: That's not what @sectretquirrel suggested. He suggested using `select()/poll()/epoll()` instead of spin looping, not instead of non-blocking mode.

Comment: tcpdump will receive any packet. Otherwise, an interface will drop any packet not matching its assigned IP

Comment: Is your computer's IP address 192.168.121.1?

Comment: @user253751 If it wasn't he would have got a `bind()` error. But he should certainly bind to INADDR_ANY unless he has a good reason otherwise.

Comment: @user253751 That's the address of the network card connected to the device. The computer also has network cards with other addresses connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a system that uses iptables, check that you aren't dropping packets. tcpdump will show packets that are incoming before they get to iptables.

Another thing is that you should be using [epoll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) or [select](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to read from the socket in a more controlled way. EAGAIN isn't neccessarily wrong: it just means there's no data. But you're whizzing round that while loop without waiting, so I'd expect lots of EAGAIN's until something actually arrives at the port.

Comment: `sudo iptables -L` shows no rules, just `(policy accept)`. Do you know any other OS configuration that could cause the packets to be dropped? And yes, there are many `EAGAIN`s but no matter how long I wait, the socket doesn't end up receiving anything unfortunately (while tcpdump does).

Comment: instead of binding to that ip, you should set it to INADDR_ANY and see if you receive data.